# Integration of python libraries in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

[directory_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOErF.jpg)

Hey everyone, I am a begginer programmer trying to make a web app with AWS, and I have been trying to make bs4 work, but it keeps coming up with the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'bs4'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I have even installed the library locally in the same directory, and zipped it and uploaded it, but it still comes up this error?

Comment: Could you add a picture/sample of the directory structure that you have right now?

Comment: @Dheeraj I have attached the image. Its in the image link.

Answer (score 1):

Hey so I got the solution!

I basically made a virtualenv and followed some steps to enable the libraries to work. Also note, the requests library doesn't seem to work due to a certificate error.

This is the page I used to fix my issue:

https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/import-custom-python-packages-on-aws-lambda-function-5fbac36b40f8

For any begginers like me, you can do this for any version of python per requirement, as I used python 3.8. This should also work for almost all python libraries!

Comment: Oh, that's great. Regarding the certificate issue, using a verify=false with the request method would allow you to run it until you get a valid certificate.